# Fatal error: Class 'SimplePie_Misc' not found in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\simplepie\library\SimplePie.php on line 59

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

I started using simplepie for RSS and I encountered this error in the very first stage itself.

**Fatal error: Class 'SimplePie_Misc' not found in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\simplepie\library\SimplePie.php on line 59**

**EDIT**
The main folder is called 'simplepie'
The sub folders and files are

1. build
2. cache
3. compatibilty_test
4. css
5. idn
6. includes
7. library(has SimplePie.php and a folder called SimplePie)
8. tests
9. index.php

**THIS IS THE CODE**

```
<?php  

//Load simplepie library  
require_once 'includes/autoloader.php';  

//new simplepie
$feed = new SimplePie();  

//address of multiple feeds
$feed->set_feed_url(array(
'http://crazyanagh.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default'
));  

//enabling cache
$feed->enable->cache(true);
$feed->set_cache_location('cache');
$feed->set_cache_duration(1800);

//start the process
$feed->init();  

//handle all types(RSS, Atoms)
$feed->handle_content_type();

?>  


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" />  
    <title>RSS Thing!</title>  
</head>  

<body>  

    <div id="container">
        <h1> SimplePie RSS Thing</h1>  
    </div><!--end container-->  

</body>
```

Comment: Hard to answer without any code... Did you include all necessary files?

Comment: I'm sorry Reeno. I've edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong. Are you sure about the path to autoloader.php? I thought it would be in the php directory, but maybe that's just with 1.3.1. Have you checked directory and file permissions on the SimplePie folders and files?

Answer (score -2):

One thing you make a mistake in cache first line. Should be **enable_cache**